# CC430F6137 UART Problem When Powered DC Supply

Tags: uart, msp430

I have a problem with my system and I can't handle the problem. Problem is that ;
When I powered the system with DC volt (3.3 v) without debugging then I can't see anything on the receiver side (Arduino Uno as receiver). However if I use debugger[FET430 - UIF ] then I can see all of the characters on the receiver side.

This is my code :

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include "cc430x613x.h"
#include <msp430.h>
#include <string.h>
void terminal_write();
void UART_open();
void UART_close();
void main(void) {

WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer
//__delay_cycles( 2 * 1e7);
while(1)

{
    UART_open();
    printf("system working\r\n");
terminal_write("AT\r\n");

__delay_cycles(5000000);

//_bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits + GIE);
    UART_close();

}

}

void terminal_write(char *info)
{
unsigned int i;


unsigned int len = strlen(info) ; 
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{

UCA0TXBUF=info[i];
__delay_cycles(10000);

}
}

void UART_open(){
        P1SEL |= BIT5 + BIT6;
        //UART Settings
        UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST; 
        UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL0 ; // ACLK
        UCA0BR0=3;   //UCA0BR0 = 3 ; //32Khz / 9600 –>> 3 
        UCA0BR1=0;   //UCA0BR1=0; // BAUD 9600;     ( UCABR1 * 256 ) + UCABR0  = UCABRx    see "slau259e.pdf"

        UCA0MCTL=6 ; //  see "slau259e.pdf" page 602 //
        //UCA0MCTL =| BIT7 |  BIT6  | BIT5 | BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1 | BIT0 |
        //          |------- UCBRFx --------------|----UCBRSx----------|UCOS16|
        // for 9600 baudrate at 32kHz UCBRFx = 0 , UCBRSx = 3 , UCOS16 = 0
        //          |  0   | 0      | 0    | 0    | 0    | 1    | 1    | 0    |
        //          0b00000110 = 0x06 = 6
        UCA0CTL1  &=~  UCSWRST;// 
        UCA0CTL1  |=   UCDORM;
}
void UART_close(){
    
    P1SEL &= ~(BIT5 + BIT6);
    UCA0CTL1  |=  UCSWRST;
    UCA0CTL1  &=~  UCDORM;
    
}

Beside if I use DC power then the system consumption is about 450-550 uA. If I use debugger then the DC power consumption is raises to about 4.8 mA . Also if I only use the debugger [powered with debugger voltage without using any external DC supply] then system can't handle the communication properly. 

If there is a solutiion I'll very appreciate.
```

Comment: This does not sound like a software problem. Try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Ah , thank you , I didn't know the electronics exchange. I'll try my chance in there :)

Answer (score 0):

[Firtina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13404947/f%C4%B1rt%C4%B1na-h%C3%BCseyin-g%C3%96kta%C5%9E), is it possible that you are only connecting the DC power supply to the analog voltage input (AVSS) and not the digital input (DVCC)? If so, then my explanation is the JTAG tool is supplying the CCF6137 chip with proper power, but when disconnected the chip doesn't have power to the digital side. If this is the case, then try connecting the DC power supply to both AVSS and DVCC pins and test again without the JTAG tool. Also, check that you are giving the chip proper ground.